# eBay Trade API - AddFixedPriceListing (21919136 : Required Minimum Number Of Photos) But Photo Is Included

Tags: image, api, ebay-api

I have been trying to get this call working for hours and im suck. I am using UploadSiteHostedPictures in order to get the image uploaded to EPS. Once the image is uploaded i am calling addFixedPriceListing. The relivant xml looks like this:

```
   <PictureDetails>
         <PictureSource>EPS</PictureSource>
        <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
       <PictureURL>http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/llEAAOSwFqNZWmCo/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>    
     </PictureDetails
```

My items were getting listed on the sandbox, but even then no photos were showing up. Any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: I will check it and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it wasn't in any of ebays sample code. You need to include `<PhotoDisplay>None</PhotoDisplay>` and `<PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay>`

```
<PictureDetails>
     <PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay>
     <PictureURL>URL_HERE</PictureURL>
     <PhotoDisplay>None</PhotoDisplay>
</PictureDetails>
```

Hope this helps some one else down the road